# Func<string,T> delegate injection with Ninject use open generics

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject, ioc-container

Following is my interface design:

```
public interface IDomainRepository<in TRequest,out TResponse>
{
    Task<IEnumerable<TResponse>> QueryAsync(TRequest inputParameters);
}
```

Since I have lot of entities, so was keen to use open generic binding as follows, thus it takes care of all the bindings:

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(IDomainRepository<,>))
      .To(typeof(CommonDomainRepository<,>)).Named("Common");
```

Challenge is in using `Func delegate` based injection, so that name binding can be passed at the run-time, something like:

```
kernel.Bind<Func<string, IDomainRepository<ManualInput, ManualEntity>>>()
      .ToMethod(ctx => name => kernel.Get<IDomainRepository<ManualInput, ManualEntity>>(name));
```

But for the `Func injection`, I am unable to use the `open generics`, due to which I have create closed generic based binding, which is leading to lots and lots of binding code (as there are 300+ entities), is there way to:

1. Use the Func delegate with open generics ?
2. Any replacement of Func delegate, since here we pass the name for named binding at run-time, which is why Interface allowing open generic cannot be directly injected ?

**Edit 1: (Why Named Binding)**

The reason for the named binding is, I need to redirect few `IDomainRepository` bindings to a different class, which need auto-mapping between data and domain entity, in few other cases it is multiple domain entities being fetched, (they have same number of generic types, which are resolved at run-time for different functionality) for e.g:

> **Mapping for fetching 2 domain entities**

```
kernel.Bind<Func<string, IDomainRepository<ManualInput, ManualEntity1,ManualEntity2>>>()
          .ToMethod(ctx => name => kernel.Get<IDomainRepository<ManualInput, ManualEntity1,ManualEntity2>>(name));
```

> **Mapping for fetching 1 domain entity, which is Mapped from a Data entity using AutoMapper**

```
kernel.Bind<Func<string, IDomainRepository<ManualInput, ManualEntity, ManualEntityData>>>()
          .ToMethod(ctx => name => kernel.Get<IDomainRepository<ManualInput, ManualEntity, ManualEntityData>>(name));
```

Comment: Curious why that binding is named. If possible to work without name when remove it.

Comment: @Nkosi, please check **Edit 1: (Why Named Binding)**, idea is to redirect to the different set of classes with same number of generic types, in one case two domain entities are fetched, in other case only one domain entity fetched but its internally mapped using a Data entity that comes from database